# Reverse an integer value within the int limit

Tags: java

I want to reverse an integer. I have trying by the following code, the problems occurs when the number is so large that its reverse gets larger than the int limit (for example 1534236469), so in that case it returns some garbage integer.

How can I make use of `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE`  to check if the reversed number is within the limits?

Note: it must use `int` variable type only.

```
int num = 1534236469;

int reverseInt = 0;
int multiplier = 1;

if ( num < 0 ) {
    multiplier *= -1;
}

while ( num != 0 ) {

    //get the last digit
    int digit = num % 10;

    //multiply the reverseInt by 10 and then add the last digit
    reverseInt = (reverseInt * multiplier) + digit;

    multiplier = 10;
    num /= 10;
}

//how to fix this.
if (reverseInt < Integer.MIN_VALUE || reverseInt > Integer.MAX_VALUE ) {
    System.out.println("Invalid number");
} else {
    System.out.println("Reversed integer is " + reverseInt);
        }
```

Comment: Do you **have** to make use of `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE`?

Comment: @Scratte No, that's just what came to my mind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just have to make the check before you add the next digit, so you can simply move your check up to the actual calculation. If your current reversed positive number is greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE/10`, then you can't add another digit. Likewise with negative numbers.

The only thing I did was move this part of your code up:

```
if (reverseInt < Integer.MIN_VALUE || reverseInt > Integer.MAX_VALUE ) {
    System.out.println("Invalid number");
} else {
```

then I added the `/10` and a `return` statement, since the program must end when there's an overflow:

```
public class StackOverflowTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num = -1534236469;

    int reverseInt = 0;
    int multiplier = 1;

    if ( num < 0 ) {
        multiplier *= -1;
    }

    while ( num != 0 ) {

        // if this next step will push is into overflow, then stop:
        if (reverseInt < Integer.MIN_VALUE/10 || reverseInt > Integer.MAX_VALUE/10) {
          System.out.println("Invalid number");
          return;

        } else {

          //get the last digit
          int digit = num % 10;

          // multiply the reverseInt by 10 and then add the last digit
          reverseInt = (reverseInt * multiplier) + digit;
        }

        multiplier = 10;
        num /= 10;
    }

    System.out.println("Reversed integer is " + reverseInt);
  }
}
```

---

Alternatively you can treat it as a String, and then simply reverse the String (along with fiddling with the sign):

```
public class StackOverflowTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    reverse(1534236469);
    System.out.println();
    reverse(-153423646);
  }

  public static void reverse(int num) { 
    System.out.println("int = " + num);
    int number = num < 0 ? -num : num;           // remove the sign

    String reverse = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(number)).reverse().toString();
    System.out.println("reverse String: " + reverse);

    try {
      int reversed = Integer.parseInt(reverse);
      reversed = num < 0 ? -reversed : reversed;  // get back the sign
      System.out.println("Reversed integer is " + reversed);
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
      System.out.println("Invalid number");
    }
  }
}
```

Prints:

```
int = 1534236469
reverse String: 9646324351
Invalid number

int = -153423646
reverse String: 646324351
Reversed integer is -646324351
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java 8+, change to:

```
reverseInt = Math.addExact(Math.multiplyExact(reverseInt, multiplier), digit);
```

The code will now throw `ArithmeticException` if the result overflows.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever the value of `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is exceeded, it starts from `Integer.MIN_VALUE` i.e. `Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1` evaluates to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. You can use this feature to get the solution you are looking for.

Simply multiply `reverseInt` in a loop from `1` to `10` and if the value becomes negative, it means that the next value (`reverseInt * multiplier`) will exceed `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Also, you need to add `reverseInt * multiplier` in a loop to a value from `0` to `9` and if the value becomes negative, it means that the next value (`reverseInt * multiplier + digit`) will exceed `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        int num = 1534236469;
        boolean valid = true;
        int reverseInt = 0;
        int multiplier = 1;

        if (num < 0) {
            multiplier *= -1;
        }

        while (num != 0) {
            // get the last digit
            int digit = num % 10;

            for (int i = 1; i <= multiplier; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j <= 9; j++) {
                    if (reverseInt * i < 0 || (reverseInt * i + j) < 0) {
                        System.out.println("Invalid number");
                        valid = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!valid) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!valid) {
                break;
            }

            // multiply the reverseInt by 10 and then add the last digit
            reverseInt = reverseInt * multiplier + digit;

            multiplier = 10;
            num /= 10;
        }
        if (valid) {
            System.out.println("Reversed integer is " + reverseInt);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Invalid number
```